# What is wrong about Hashmap

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, compiler-errors, hashmap

I'm using Hashmap in Android studio version 1.7.
But i'm following code from old website.
I don't know about new platform of new `Hashmap`.
I can run application. Don't has error in logcat.
Please see my picture and help me.
Sorry for my bad English.

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong here. In Java 7 or later, you can use an empty set of type arguments (<>)  to invoke the constructor of a generic class. Example: Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize your `Arraylist` by following way:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with it. The dialog shown by Android Studio is just a hint that you could write it a bit simpler.